# How to change the order in which a recursive function is executed in Java?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to index a lot of tags in an XML document using JAVA DOM parser to form a MIB-like structure from it (e.g

```
<module>
    <container>
        <list>
            <leaf></leaf>
            <leaf></leaf>
...
```

I want module to be mapped to 1, container to 1.1, list to 1.1.1, leaf to 1.1.1.1 and the other leaf to 1.1.1.2 (I have methods that do this already) But I am having problems when the same named XML tags are nested.
Here is the function I've created - Just printing out the attribute names for simplicity

```
public static void traverse(Node node) {
    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        // gets the current node
        Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);

        if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            traverse(currentNode);
        }

        if (currentNode.getNodeName().equals("container")) {
            for (int j = 0; j < currentNode.getChildNodes().getLength(); j++) {
                if (currentNode.getChildNodes().item(j).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element e = (Element) currentNode.getChildNodes().item(j);
                    System.out.println(e.getAttribute("name") + " "
                            + currentNode.getChildNodes().item(j).getNodeName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is a sample of the XML I'm trying to parse:

```
<container name="alarm">
    <list name="config">
        <leaf name="source">
            <type name="larmSourceType" />
            <description>
                <text>The name</text>
            </description>
            <mandatory value="true" />
        </leaf>
        <leaf name="name">
            <type name="atNameType" />
            <description>
                <text>fies each alarm within the named alarm source</text>
    </list>
    <container name="stat">
        <leaf name="currentActiveAlarms">
            <type name="atc:alarmCounterType" />
        </leaf>
    </container>
</container>
```

When I run my method on this program the output shows that the second, nested container node is executed first and all of the leaves in that one get printed. Whereas I would like to print all from the first container, and then the second.

I hope this makes sense? P.S sorry about the formatting, I couldn't figure it out.
Thanks

Comment: Please learn to format, instructions for how to do it are just a click away. I have done it for you this time, but you should do it for yourself in the future if you want to make it more likely for people to help you and to avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap your code so that you do stuff with the current node first and traverse after that:

```
public static void traverse(Node node) {
    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        // gets the current node
        Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);

        // Do stuff with current node first
        if (currentNode.getNodeName().equals("container")) {
            for (int j = 0; j < currentNode.getChildNodes().getLength(); j++) {
                if (currentNode.getChildNodes().item(j).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element e = (Element) currentNode.getChildNodes().item(j);
                    System.out.println(e.getAttribute("name") + " "
                            + currentNode.getChildNodes().item(j).getNodeName());
                }
            }
        }

        // traverse deeper after having done stuff with current node (above)
        if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            traverse(currentNode);
        }
    }
}
```

This will print the parent nodes before their children rather than the other way around.

Comment: @Spdollaz If it answers your question then please accept this answer. Thanks.